# Random Question about limits and convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

I am taking my first analysis course and the notion of limits implying convergence or not is some what blurry.

Can you think of a sequence $s_k$ for which $s_{k+1} - s_k$ goes to 0 but for which $s_k$ doesn't converge? and if so why is the existence of that limit not sufficient for convergence?

Answer (score 1):

Convergence depends *crucially* on the space the sequence takes values:

Pick $s_n = 1/n$ in $(0,1)$. Notice that as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then the distance between two terms is getting smaller and smaller, but $s_n$ is not converging to a point **in** $(0,1)$. This is an example of what is called a Cauchy sequence. Note that in particular spaces it may be the case that cauchy sequences do not converge. In the real line this is impossible since $\mathbb{R}$ is [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers).

Another example: Take the space of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$. Try to see what I mean by taking a sequence with rational numbers $q_n$ that converge to an irrational number.